# Shortcodes with split content

Tags: wordpress

I'm using this function to split the content

```
function split_content() {
  global $more;
  $more = true;
  $content = preg_split('/<span id="more-\d+"><\/span>/i', get_the_content('more'));
  for($c = 0, $csize = count($content); $c < $csize; $c++) {
    $content[$c] = apply_filters('the_content', $content[$c]);
  }
  return $content;
}
```

Now I'm using a shortcode to display an icon, the problem is that no mater where i put it in the content, it always is displayed before the split content function, is the're a way to do the shortcode after the split content function?

**The shortcode function**

```
add_shortcode( 'ikona', 'add_device_icon' );

function add_device_icon($attr){
  global $post;
  $icons = array(0=>'wybierz',1=>'piekarnik',2=>'frytkownica',3=>'mikrofalówka',4=>'patelnia',5=>'garnek',6=>'grill',7=>'opiekacz');
  $icon_number = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'product-icon-type', true );

  extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'do' => ''), $atts ) );

  $style='';
  if($do!=''){
    $style = 'style="float:left"';
  }
  echo "<span class='icon-$icon_number' title='{$icons[$icon_number]}' $style></span>";
}
```

The content is displayed in the wordpress loop

```
<div class='holder'>
  <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
  <?php $content = split_content() ?>
  <?php echo $content[0] ?>
  <?php if(count($content )> 1 ) :?>
      <a href="#" class="seemore">zobacz więcej&hellip;</a>
  <?php endif ?>
</div>
<div class="more">
    <?php echo $content[1] ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Add more code for people to help you out. Particularly, add the code that generates the shortcode, and somewhere that you call split_content() from.

Comment: Any chance your icon shortcode is echoing, rather than returning, the code generated?

Comment: Yes it does - man this is so embarrassing :) It fixed the problem thank you